# How to make averages on attributes for the objects with duplicate names in list?

Tags: java, list, average

I have a list of objects that have the following attributes :

```
String processName;
float CPU;
float mem;
```

I want to rank top objects by their names and CPU/mem attributes, but some processes appear more than once in the list but with different CPU/mem loads.
The output I get:

TOP 10 PROCESSES BY CPU USAGE:

```
PROCESS NAME: "process1" | CPU: 23.91 | MEMORY: 99.86

PROCESS NAME: "process2" | CPU: 12.4 | MEMORY: 24.95

PROCESS NAME: "process1" | CPU: 11.82 | MEMORY: 24.96

PROCESS NAME: "process1" | CPU: 11.68 | MEMORY: 24.96

PROCESS NAME: "process2" | CPU: 9.2 | MEMORY: 183.6

PROCESS NAME: "process3" | CPU: 4.09 | MEMORY: 21.64

PROCESS NAME: "process3" | CPU: 2.01 | MEMORY: 3.23

PROCESS NAME: "process4" | CPU: 2.0 | MEMORY: 3.23

PROCESS NAME: "process4" | CPU: 1.86 | MEMORY: 2.48

PROCESS NAME: "process3" | CPU: 1.86 | MEMORY: 2.48
```

The output I am aiming for:

```
PROCESS NAME: "process1" | CPU: avgCPU1 | MEMORY: avgMem1

PROCESS NAME: "process2" | CPU: avgCPU2  | MEMORY: avgMem2

PROCESS NAME: "process3" | CPU: avgCPU3  | MEMORY: avgMem3 

PROCESS NAME: "process4" | CPU: avgCPU4  | MEMORY: avgMem4

...

PROCESS NAME: "process10" | CPU: avgCPU10 | MEMORY: avgMem10
```

How could I approach making an average for the objects with duplicate names?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

The code I am using for adding the top 10 processes is the following:

```
CPUMEMProcesses.sort(ProcessCPUMEM.CpuProcessComparator);
diagInformation.append("\n\nTOP 10 PROCESSES BY CPU USAGE: \n\n");
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    diagInformation.append(CPUMEMProcesses.get(j) + "\n");
}
```

I am appending each result to a stringBuilder named `diagInformation` in order to print it to a file later.

```
ArrayList<ProcessCPUMEM> CPUMEMProcesses = new ArrayList<ProcessCPUMEM>();
```

And I am adding elements in the above ArrayList, one by one, as I am reading them from a different binary file.

Comment: Show us the code you're using.

Comment: I have added a short edit showing how I get my current outputs in a nutshell.

Comment: before outputting create a `Map` out of the List, where you accumulate the vavlues and then iterate over the `Map` for the output

Comment: "How could I approach making an average for the objects with duplicate names?" How would you solve this problem by hand? I suggest that you back away from the Java code and solve a simple example with pencil, paper, and a calculator. Think about the steps you take to do this and write them down **in words**.